# why sympy subs() not changing anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

This is maybe the most basic operation but still i had some issues, nothing changes after subs(), i understand the concept of sympy but what i am missing? I am trying to output a float value for epsilon.

```
a = 30 # MPa
k1 = 0.82
b = 365

bw = 300 # mm
hw = 600 # mm
p = 40 # mm 

a1 = 1071 # mm^2
a2 = 1071 # mm^2
d = hw - p #
E = 2e5

c = sym.Symbol('c')
fcd = a/1.5
Fc = 0.85*fcd*bw*k1*c
epsilon = (0.003 * (c-p))/c
Fsu = epsilon*E*a2
Fs = a1 * b
expr = (Fc + Fsu - Fs)
c = sym.solve([expr],(c))
c = c[1]
z = epsilon.subs(c,c)
```

Comment: It usually is recommended to use different variables when they mean something different. Now you are using `c` in 3 ways.  You could do `c = sym.Symbol('c')`, and then `c_sol = sym.solve([expr],(c))`; `c_sol0 = c_sol[0]` and `z = epsilon.subs(c, c_sol0)`

Comment: i changed like you said. but gave me  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'Tuple' and 'NegativeOne' error.

Comment: Did you check the format of the results of `solve`?  Depending on the type of equations, that can be lists or dictionaries or combinations. You could try `c_sol0 = c_sol[0][0]`

Comment: i edited my first comment but somehow it didn't change. Anyways i solved the problem thanks! it is working